# Android Inputbox - FMX

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10.1-berlin

Is there anyway I can use an InputBox for android? I have tried looking online but found nothing. I'm not sure if it's something to do with permissions or what.

I have tried using this method but still no luck:

[New Non Blocking InputBox Function In Delphi XE7 Firemonkey On Android And IOS](http://www.fmxexpress.com/new-non-blocking-inputbox-function-in-delphi-xe7-firemonkey-on-android-and-ios/)

I'm using Android 6.0.1 and Android 25.2.5 SDK and API 25.

The InputBox is grayed out

[image: Screenshot]

and when using it:

[image: Screenshot]

I'm new to FireMonkey.

Comment: See http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE7/en/What's_New_in_Delphi_and_C%2B%2BBuilder_XE7#Dialog_Box_Methods_Support_Anonymous_Methods_to_Handle_Their_Closing, in particular the next to last paragraph under that heading, which says *If you call InputBox, InputQuery, or MessageDlg and **you do not provide an anonymous method on your call**, these methods behave as they used to behave in XE6: **calls are blocking on all platforms, including iOS, and Android is not supported**. *

Comment: Did you read the message from the screen shot that you included? If so, why not observe its content. If mot, why not?

Comment: I did read it but i'm struggling with it. I don't know how to do what it asks and looking online for it just gives me a more complex tutorial

Answer (score 2):

You can use the inputbox like this. Remember that the inputbox is not modal. User answer is handled in the anonymous method that is provided as 4th parameter.

```
  InputBox('Box Caption','Box prompt','Default value',
    procedure(const AResult: TModalResult; const AValue: string)
    begin
      // This is executed when user closes the input box
      // Check result and value here and do whatever is needed
    end
    );
```